# Retrieving the pixel position of text in an image or document in C#

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, asp.net-core, ocr

I have a word document that has hidden anchor tags in it that need to be replaced with items on the web.

**For example:**

User uploads a word doc with anchor tags such as "/textbox/".

1. I am taking this document and converting it to a png and placing it
   in a web page as its actually size.
2. I am making the div that the image is sitting in position: Relative
   using css.
3. Then I would like to use position: Absolute to place an HTML input
   field exactly in the location that the "/textbox/" anchor tag was.

The problem is that I do not know if I should be determining the pixel location of the anchor tags prior to converting to png or after converting to png. Or if converting from word doc to pdf would be easier to determine the position.

I am using a third-party tool to do all of my document/image conversions and I am sure they have a text reading tool. But any info on how to get the text position in pixels would be great.

Comment: What is the third party tool? Any use of Interop libraries?

Comment: @OzanGunceler No use of Interop libraries since most of them don't work with .net core. LeadTools.Documents is what I use. It can do any document/image conversion combo and has an OCR tool. I just don't even know where to start with figuring out the pixel position of string of text whether it be in a word doc, pdf, or png. I just know that when it comes to the web I ultimately need to know the pixel location of the anchor tags based on the png.

Comment: Sorry, missed the .net core part. I believe each file type would require a separate approach. Why don't you try to convert the DOC file directly to HTML and then work wih the HTML markup? https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Convert-DOC-file-to-HTML-101ca8fb